# Time stamp from MySql to PHP displaying December/31/1969

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I have for the code:

```
<?php
    $link = "SELECT * FROM epk";
    echo '<b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" color="#FF6666">' . date("m.d.Y", strtotime($startTime)) . '</b>';
?>
```

I read a lot of the different fixes on this site, but I can't seem to translate it to my line of code. I didn't write this, but the person that did it for me has become unreachable. If anyone can tell my how to fix this I would appreciate it.

Thank you VERY much!

---

CORRECTION:

I'm so sorry. I have no idea why I posted that code. That was not the original one, what I posted was one I found that I tried to mess with. THIS is the original one that I have now that used to work:

```
<?php $link = "SELECT * FROM epk"; echo '<b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1" color="#FF6666">' . date("m-d-y",strtotime($r['date'])) . '</b>'; ?>
```

Many thanks! :)

---

### *CORRECTION*

I got it... for what I had, I just made a wild guess and added the letters "OW" to the $r line and it worked. Here it is, and hopefully it can help someone else out if they see this...

```
<?php $link = "SELECT * FROM epk"; echo '<b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1" color="#FF6666">' . date("m-d-y",strtotime($row['date'])) . '</b>'; ?>
```

Hope that helps someone else out too.

Comment: Try echoing $startTime to make sure the value is what you think it is.

Comment: Where are you setting $startTime? A little more code would be useful.

Comment: You should not try to fix this on your own if you do not know what you are doing. Chances are you will only make it worse and harder to fix.

Comment: Do you know where the $r variable comes from in your code?

Comment: The problem is basically the same. Just this time, `$r` doesn't seem to be defined, instead of `$startTime`. It sounds as though you need to get a developer in to look at your code. @Resorath's answer is almost certainly correct, but if you can't understand it, there's not much more we can do for you on Stack Overflow. You either need to learn PHP, or get someone to go through your code.

Comment: is the variable $r mentioned anywhere else in the script? $r looks like it contains a line from a database record, but your code does not show us how this record is being obtained. do a search for $r and see what other lines of code come up, then post here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your missing some information here.

Your $startTime variable is not initialized in this code, it is never "set" anywhere. So your essentially passing "0" into your strtotime function. This means "0 seconds after the Unix Epoche, December 31, 1969 at midnight".

You would need to run the query called "link" first, and extract the data stored in the resulting query and pass that into the variable $startTime.

Basically, your missing a bunch of code here.

Comment: I appreciate your fast response, however that is all greek to me. This was something that I had within a page that was written back in 2005. It seemed to work then for some reason.

Sorry I had to edit this because I hit ENTER and it posted it. BUT... this is within a page of other scripts. The table in the database is 'date' and the time in the cell right now says '02-27-2012'

Comment: @Peredy, unfortunately without knowing your database schema I would have no idea what to offer, I don't know what is inside the "epk" table. You might need to hire a developer. Your just missing a lot of code, and I don't see how this would have ever worked, unless there is more code that you didn't include.

Comment: @Peredy, Okay, in response to your edit, you will need to look at http://ca3.php.net/mysql_query and http://ca.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: Sorry Peredy, your edit doesn't change anything. Please see @dqhendricks comment, he speaks the truth. I can give you the fish now, but I don't want you to come back here fishing when something else goes wrong (is that how the cliche goes? I'm bad at cliches).

Comment: Yes but doesn't my edit give more definition to what the starttime thing is calling for?

Answer (score 3):

That is what happens when strtotime() returns false, because it failed to decode whatever is contained in $startTime, meaning $startTime wasn't a valid date string and therefore the strtotime() function cannot be used on it.

What do you think is contained in $startTime? Did you put anything in that variable before your above snippet of code, or is it just an undefined variable because you never defined it?

**EDIT**

You could try this, but without knnowing anything about your system, you could be messing things up worse by using this code. it seems as though at least two lines are missing in the snippet you showed above, but there could be more. as for how those lines would turn up missing out of the blue, i can only suggest that someone has access to your server and is deleting lines of code. either that, or you are not showing us a crucial piece of code that occurs before your snippet, which pulls data from the database.

here is my dark alley guess as to what may fix your code. use at your own risk.

```
<?php
   $link = "SELECT * FROM epk";
   $response = mysql_query($query);
   $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($response);
   echo '<b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1" color="#FF6666">' . date("m-d-y",strtotime($r['date'])) . '</b>';
?>
```

Comment: In the database cell for 'date' it says: 02-27-2012
That snippet of code is within a page of other html and php. I could list the whole page script but it's rather long.

Comment: @Peredy it doesn't matter what is in the database. your code snippet (even the revised one) never runs the query that is contained in $link, and therefore nothing is being grabbed from the database. if i had to guess, i'd say that there is a couple of lines missing between the first and second line which should contain code for querying the database, and then grabbing the first record within the database's response.

Comment: as i said, I would not mess with this if you do not understand it. you should hired someone who knows what they are doing, otherwise you may introduce new bugs into your system and not even realize it.

Comment: This is what I copied and pasted in it's place from a different part of the page that also calls from the database. It now displays it, but it displays it as it is in the table... and not like a traditional m/d/y format. I don't mind the time being in there but it's too much overkill in my opinion

<?php $link = "SELECT * FROM epk"; echo '<font color="#FF6666" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"size="2" >'.$row["date"].'</font>'; ?>

Comment: @Peredy use date("m-d-y",strtotime($row['date']))

Comment: Yes thats actually exactly what I did. All that was wrong with it was the "OW" letters after the $r.

Comment: @Peredy so... how did those get cut out of the line in the first place?